# Why Python requires Sub-Package imports for some Types (and not Others)

Tags: python

For example:

```
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

Here we called load_workbook directy from openpyxl

```
from openpyxl.chart import Barchart,Reference
```

Here we are calling these  Barchart,Reference  classes from chart file  not directly from openpyxl package, why?  Can't we just write:

```
from openpyxl import Barchart,Reference 

wb= xl.load_workbook('transaction.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
cell = sheet.cell(1,1)

print(cell.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the author chose to [expose `load_workbook`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/15df72eae2f93bedc0c0c0cc8753b9107cc82d41/openpyxl/__init__.py#lines-8) directly from the top level of the package, while `chart` lives in a sub-package and did not receive the same treatment.  It's not so much a function of Python but of how the authors chose to expose their API.